# What do the angular momentum quantum numbers in a spherically symmetric potential physically represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Are there any nice ways to visualise or imagine what the angular momentum quantum numbers in a spherically symmetric potential, $j$ and $m$, represent other than just solutions to the wavefunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $j$ is usually associated with the magnitude of the angular momentum vector while $m$ is the projection on the $z$-axis. From this it becomes clear why $-j\leq m\leq j$, since the projection of a vector along an axis can’t be more than the size of the vector itself.

To be a bit more precise, we know $L_z$ and $L^2=L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$ are commuting observables. The eigenvalues of $L^2$ are given by $j(j+1)$, where $j$ is a positive integer, while the compatible eigenvalues of $L_z$ are integers $m$, with $|m|\leq j$.

(Here I’m taking $\hbar=1$.)